# Send message to channel in a function

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have an event handler for the ready event.
ready.js:

```
const { Events } = require('discord.js');
const db = require("../config/database");
const itemdb = require("../config/itemdb");
const items = require("../models/items");
const AHItems = require('../models/ahitems.js');
const RSS = require('../models/regionserversettings.js');

module.exports = {
    name: Events.ClientReady,
    once: true,
    execute(client) {
        console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
        db.authenticate()
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Logged in to DB!');
                AHItems.init(db);
                AHItems.sync();
                RSS.init(db);
                RSS.sync();
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        itemdb.authenticate()
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Logged in to Item DB!');
                items.init(itemdb);
                items.sync();
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));

    },
};
```

From inside the execute block I can use client.channels.cache.get('xxxxxx').send('Hello');

I want to use the send method in another File:

```
const AHItems = require("../models/ahitems");
const RSS = require("../models/regionserversettings");
const getprice = require("../api/getcurrentPrice");
const client = require("../events/ready");
const pricealarm = async function()
{
    let ahitems = await AHItems.findAll({attributes: ['guildID', 'itemID']});
    for (let i = 0; i < ahitems.length; i++)  {
        const guild = ahitems[i].dataValues.guildID;
        const RSSData = await RSS.findOne({where: {guildID: guild}});
        const item = ahitems[i].dataValues.itemID;
        const access_token = RSSData.AccessToken;
        const server = RSSData.serverID;
        const price = await getprice(access_token, item, server);
        const channel = client.channels.cache.get('x').send('test');
        console.log(channel);
    }
}
module.exports = pricealarm;
```

But if I try to do this, it tells me 'Unresolved function or method send()'
I think I am requiring the wrong file, but am unsure, which one I have to require

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you are trying to use the `send()` method from an object client that has not been properly instantiated in the file where you want to use it. In your *ready.js* file, you correctly initialize the client object and can use its `send()` method inside the execute block.

However, in the other file where you want to use the `send()` method, you import the *ready.js* file, but you are only importing the module, not the instantiated client object. Therefore, the `send()` method is unresolved and cannot be called.

To fix this issue, you need to modify the *ready.js* file to export the client object in addition to the module.exports statement. For example, you can add the following line at the end of the execute block:

```
module.exports.client = client;
```

Then, in your other file, you can import the client object by requiring the ready.js file and accessing the client property of the exported module. For example:

```
const ready = require("../events/ready");
const client = ready.client;

// Now you can use client.channels.cache.get('xxxxxx').send('Hello');
```

With these modifications, you should be able to properly use the `send()` method from the client object in both files.